# Ubuntu 16.10 GTK 3.0 Include Path for Headers

Tags: compiling, gtk, gtk3

I went to the site: 
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html 
and typed in the example-0.c (I renamed it as First_Window.c). However, I get the message after this command to compile:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+3.0` -o First_Window First_Window.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Package gtk+3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+3.0' found
First_Window.c:8:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include

After editing the include file to path: `#include </usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>`, I then receive a new error.

Package gtk+3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+3.0' found
In file included from First_Window.c:9:0:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30:21: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory
 #include

Found some articles on exporting the path. I can't find them now, but none of them worked anyway.

Will someone either tell me how to set or export the path or solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing a '-' sign in your first pkg-config statement. Try adding the '-' sign so that the entire command is:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o First_Window First_Window.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

You should also amend the include path back to how it was before:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

And then try compiling again.

Gnome offers more help on using/testing pkg-config [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-compiling.html).